# Clicking the cross-reference sends me to the wrong place (below the caption instead of above), how to fix this?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, cross-reference, caption

The setting for the position of figures' caption is "Below selected item", so Word knows that the figure is above the caption.

However when I click on the cross reference I am sent in the position in the document where the caption shows at the very top of the screen - thus not showing the figure, which is above the caption.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

### The cross-reference is really to the Caption, not to the figure.

These should be kept on the same page. It is possible to group the figure and the caption to keep them on the same page. See my chapter on complex documents [part on doing this](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#MovingFigureCaption).

Figures are included in Word either in-line with text, or as a floating object/Text Box/Picture.

If in-line with text, they will be in a separate paragraph. You want the first paragraph of these to be set with paragraph formatting of "Keep with next." That keeps the two paragraphs on the same page.

If a floating graphic/object (perhaps with text wrapping around), then the Caption will be in a Text Box, which is a graphical element in Word. You need to select the figure and the Text Box containing the Caption and Group them. That keeps them on the same page.

Comment: All my figures are on the same page of the respective caption. However, considering that the figures are above the caption and that clicking on the cross-reference brings me to where that caption is seen as the first thing at the top of the screen, the fact that they are on the same page doesn't prevent the figure to be out of frame upon clicking on the cross-reference. Hope I explained myself better